# How to use highcharts to display data of only five point when the page is initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

**When the page is initialized, it displays all 20 weeks' data.**

**I want to display from 2018week1 to 2018week5, this five weeks data for employee1 and employee2, when the chart is initialized.**

When zooming on the X axis or Y axis, I should be able to chose any time period.

```js
var chart = null;
data1 = [1884, 2936, 2039, 1948, 1814, 2071, 2183, 3234, 3426, 2188, 1884, 2936, 2039, 1948, 1814, 2071, 2183, 3234, 3426, 2188]
data2 = [875, 694, 919, 1092, 815, 1137, 1421, 1547, 1737, 1748, 875, 694, 919, 1092, 815, 1137, 1421, 1547, 1737, 1748]
chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Importance'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['2017week43', '2017week44', '2017week45', '2017week46', '2017week47', '2017week48', '2017week49', '2017week50', '2017week51', '2017week52', '2018week1', '2018week2', '2018week3', '2018week4', '2018week5', '2018week6', '2018week7', '2018week8', '2018week9', '2018week10']
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Importance'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    line: {
      marker: {
        radius: 2
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      },
      lineWidth: 1,
      states: {
        hover: {
          lineWidth: 1
        }
      },
      threshold: null
    }
  },
  series: [{
      type: 'line',
      name: 'employee1',
      data: data1
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      name: 'employee2',
      data: data2
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/highcharts/modules/oldie.js"></script>
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/highcharts-plugins/highcharts-zh_CN.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width:400px;height:400px"></div>
```

The effect of the code now：
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rhaegal/vme892cn/1/)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `minRange` to 1 and `setExtremes()` to the range you want.

I also add two buttons on the upper right to change the range as you want. If you want to select a specific range, I think you have to create two `select`s by yourself and algorithm to change the range.

Edit: Added two `select`s to let user set the range.

```js
var min = 10,
  max = 14;
var chart = null;
data1 = [1884, 2936, 2039, 1948, 1814, 2071, 2183, 3234, 3426, 2188, 1884, 2936, 2039, 1948, 1814, 2071, 2183, 3234, 3426, 2188]
data2 = [875, 694, 919, 1092, 815, 1137, 1421, 1547, 1737, 1748, 875, 694, 919, 1092, 815, 1137, 1421, 1547, 1737, 1748]

var weeks = ['2017week43', '2017week44', '2017week45', '2017week46', '2017week47', '2017week48', '2017week49', '2017week50', '2017week51', '2017week52', '2018week1', '2018week2', '2018week3', '2018week4', '2018week5', '2018week6', '2018week7', '2018week8', '2018week9', '2018week10']
chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Importance'
  },
  xAxis: {
    minRange: 1,
    categories: weeks
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Importance'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    line: {
      marker: {
        radius: 2
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      },
      lineWidth: 1,
      states: {
        hover: {
          lineWidth: 1
        }
      },
      threshold: null
    }
  },
  series: [{
      type: 'line',
      name: 'employee1',
      data: data1
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      name: 'employee2',
      data: data2
    }
  ],
  exporting: {
    buttons: {
      moveRight: {
        text: '>>',
        onclick: function(){
          var canShift = max < 19
          max = canShift ? max + 1 : max;
          min = canShift ? min + 1 : min;
          chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max)
        }
      },
      increasePeriod: {
        text: '+',
        onclick: function() {
          max = max < 19 ? max + 1 : max;
          chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max)
        }
      },
      decreasePeriod: {
        text: '-',
        onclick: function() {
          max = max > min ? max - 1 : max
          chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max)
        }
      },
      moveLeft: {
        text: '<<',
        onclick: function() {
          var canShift = min > 0
          min = canShift ? min - 1 : min;
          max = canShift ? max -1 : max;
          chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max)
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

$.each(weeks, function(index, week){
  $('<option>', {
    value: index,
    text: week
  }).appendTo($('select'))
})

$('select').on('change', function(){
  min = parseInt($('#start').val());
  max = parseInt($('#end').val());
  if(min > max){
     max = min
     $('#start').val(min)
     $('#end').val(max)
  }
  chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max)
})

$('#start').val(min)
$('#end').val(max).trigger('change')

chart.showResetZoom();
```

```css
#container {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/highcharts/modules/oldie.js"></script>
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/highcharts-plugins/highcharts-zh_CN.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="rangeSelector">
  <select id="start"></select>
  <select id="end"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much!!

Comment: Note that this is not optimized. If you select to another range and click the buttons, it will start from `2018week1` again.

Comment: How can click the button to move to the left or right period?

Comment: I updated the codes. You can make your version base on this.

Comment: @Rhaegal I added two `select`s to change the display weeks.

Comment: Why the index starts from 0?Such as "min = 10" you use 10 but in fact is eleventh element.

Comment: Cause index of an array starts from 0. `min = 10` means it would start from `weeks[10]` which is `2018week1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling [`setExtremes()`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes) after the chart has been intitialized, like this:

```
var maxValue = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().max
var minValue = maxValue - 4
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(minValue, maxValue, true)
chart.showResetZoom();
```

And setting the [`minRange`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minRange) of the `xAxis`:

```
xAxis: {
  minRange: 4,
  ...
}
```

I also called `showResetZoom`, which will let the user see the "reset zoom" button.

```js
var chart = null;
data1 = [1884, 2936, 2039, 1948, 1814, 2071, 2183, 3234, 3426, 2188, 1884, 2936, 2039, 1948, 1814, 2071, 2183, 3234, 3426, 2188]
data2 = [875, 694, 919, 1092, 815, 1137, 1421, 1547, 1737, 1748, 875, 694, 919, 1092, 815, 1137, 1421, 1547, 1737, 1748]
chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Importance'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['2017week43', '2017week44', '2017week45', '2017week46', '2017week47', '2017week48', '2017week49', '2017week50', '2017week51', '2017week52', '2018week1', '2018week2', '2018week3', '2018week4', '2018week5', '2018week6', '2018week7', '2018week8', '2018week9', '2018week10'],
    minRange: 4
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Importance'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    line: {
      marker: {
        radius: 2
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      },
      lineWidth: 1,
      states: {
        hover: {
          lineWidth: 1
        }
      },
      threshold: null
    }
  },
  series: [{
      type: 'line',
      name: 'employee1',
      data: data1
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      name: 'employee2',
      data: data2
    }
  ]
});

var maxValue = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().max
var minValue = maxValue - 4
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(minValue, maxValue, true)
chart.showResetZoom();
```

```html
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/highcharts/modules/oldie.js"></script>
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/highcharts-plugins/highcharts-zh_CN.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width:400px;height:400px"></div>
```

**Jsfiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/wyp8Lfx0/1/

Comment: But I see there are six point on chart,no matter how to modify, at least six?Is there a way to set the time between 2018weeek1 and 2018week5?

Comment: Thanks very much!Thanks very much!