# Why highcharts the page does not show anything?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

**I use this code to test highcharts,but the page does not show anything,why?**

[My code](https://jsfiddle.net/Rhaegal/sxdz0kvy/)

```
data = [ {"reportYear":2017,"reportWeek":49,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":182.0},
                {"reportYear":2017,"reportWeek":51,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":231.0},
                {"reportYear":2017,"reportWeek":52,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":77.0},
                {"reportYear":2018,"reportWeek":1,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":55.0},
                {"reportYear":2018,"reportWeek":2,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":101.0},
                {"reportYear":2018,"reportWeek":3,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":982.0},
                {"reportYear":2018,"reportWeek":4,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":744.0},
                {"reportYear":2018,"reportWeek":8,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":698.0},
                {"reportYear":2018,"reportWeek":9,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":235.0},
                {"reportYear":2018,"reportWeek":12,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":657.0},
                {"reportYear":2018,"reportWeek":13,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":251.0},
                {"reportYear":2018,"reportWeek":14,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":147.0},
                {"reportYear":2018,"reportWeek":15,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":156.0},
                {"reportYear":2018,"reportWeek":19,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":481.0},
                {"reportYear":2018,"reportWeek":20,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":639.0},
                {"reportYear":2018,"reportWeek":21,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":256.0},
                {"reportYear":2018,"reportWeek":30,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":324.0},
                {"reportYear":2018,"reportWeek":31,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":852.0},
                {"reportYear":2019,"reportWeek":3,"employeeCode":100,"employeeName":"Peter","importanceDegree":361.0},
                ]
```

**When I get into the page of my code on jsfiddle.net,I feel the page is dead,Why?**

Comment: I use importanceList to display,not data to display.

Comment: @Hikarunomemory  Sir,can you help me?

Comment: @ewolden  Sir,you can see this link ,there is no "x"  .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50057627/how-to-use-highcharts-to-display-data-of-only-five-point-when-the-page-is-initia

Comment: On first glance, It seems like your data format is not like it should be according to the `series` documentation